# Oracle RAC 18c Patching - datapatch

Tags: oracle, rac, oracle-asm, oracle-18c

After patching GI Home and DB Home simultaneously using command:

```
.oraenv
+ASM1
opatchauto apply /patchlocation
```

Should i run ./datapatch from DB home or GI home? Or it doesn't matter from which home? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the Grid Infrastructure Management Repository (GIMR) a.k.a. MGMTDB (if you have it), datapatch is automatically executed as part of patching.

For regular databases, execute datapatch from the database home.